# Upgrading to OSX El Capitan

Tags: texmaker, mactex

I've read previous questions regarding these issues, but I'm new to Mac and not sure how to implement any of their solutions.

I currently have MacTeX 2015 on my MacBook, and I do all of my work inside TeXmaker. I want to upgrade to OS El Capitan, and I've read that it can mess up your documents when it comes to compiling, etc.

I've seen people write about changing `/usr/library` stuff (or something like that), but frankly, I have no idea what any of that stuff is.

If someone could please help me out and give me a step by step of what I should do to make TeXmaker/MacTeX work in OS El Capitan, I would be forever grateful!

Thanks

Comment: Are you planning also to install MacTeX 2016 after the upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Please go to <http://www.tug.org/mactex/elcapitan.html> to get more information about El Capitan. Especially take a look at the `Updating For El Capitan' article linked there; it gives instructions for updating the Preferences in TeXmaker if it doesn't update itself automatically.